# Extract / Guard promise, pull Promise<T> from mixed union

Tags: typescript

I have a union something like `Promise<string> | boolean | void` I want to be able to pass that variable into a guard function and work with it assuring it's a promise.

I am trying to make a guard for it.

```
function isPromise <T>(t: T) t is Promise<any> {
  return !!maybePromise && typeof maybePromise.then === 'function';
}
```

How can I extract the type of promise from here? Is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean the type of the promise. You are almost there I think: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEEQBd5QFwAUYHsC2AlgM4gA8RyMBAdgOYB88APvAEY45JTXPwBuOAsADcAKFEAzAK7UwyAjh7Fs+YglIAVegApk6eBt4rCJUtwCe9AJT7UxeMbVnql+AG9R8eHGRSYPAEIA1AAyEPgAcmQACxBqCPgaeFDw5HMABxAcCWSAOhi4+ABeEsjpWXlFCLEAX3ECCW1lXBMQbSgrK3dPLzR82OptImLGIlzuMGicGC7RGqA

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, what you mean saying "extract the type of promise", but you could write a guard function like this:

```
function isPromise(t: any): t is Promise<any> {
  return t instanceof Promise
}
```

And use it in your code:

```
const someVariable: Promise<string> | boolean | undefined = new Promise(r => r('myString'))

if(isPromise(someVariable)) {
  someVariable.then(result => { /* ... */ })
}
```

Actually you don't even need a guard function for this, just use `instanceof`:

```
if(someVariable instanceof Promise) {
  // ...
}
```